# How to add an exact-match flag to the following git + sed function?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, terminal, git

I want to create a bash function where you can do a sed find and replace while ignoring the files and folders in `.gitignore`. I also want to be able to add any git grep flags to the command. For example, for an exact match, I should be able to add `-w`.

This is what I have so far:

```
gs {
  local grep_options=()
  local search_pattern
  local replacement

  while [[ $1 =~ ^- ]]; do
    grep_options+=("$1")
    shift
  done

  search_pattern=$1
  replacement=$2

  git grep -l "${grep_options[@]}" "$search_pattern" | xargs sed -i "s/$search_pattern/$replacement/g"
}
```

`gs pattern replacement` will sucessfully do the search and replace. But `gs -w pattern replacement` won't do anything.

Why is this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in function declaration.

Instead of

```
w { ... }
```

you need:

```
w() { ... }
```

Always pass your scripts to https://shellcheck.net before asking help:

```
$ shellcheck file

In file line 1:
gs {
^-- SC2148 (error): Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang or a 'shell' directive.
   ^-- SC1083 (warning): This { is literal. Check expression (missing ;/\n?) or quote it.


In file line 2:
  local grep_options=()
  ^---^ SC2168 (error): 'local' is only valid in functions.


In file line 3:
  local search_pattern
  ^---^ SC2168 (error): 'local' is only valid in functions.


In file line 4:
  local replacement
  ^---^ SC2168 (error): 'local' is only valid in functions.


In file line 15:
}
^-- SC1089 (error): Parsing stopped here. Is this keyword correctly matched up?

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2148 -- Tips depend on target shell and y...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2168 -- 'local' is only valid in functions.
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1083 -- This { is literal. Check expressi...
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. But I added the `()`, and `gs -w pattern replacement` is still not matching whole words.

Comment: @wyc : `shellcheck` ... check! Now learn to use the shell debug feature `set -x` added as the 2nd line of your script. (`set +x` turns it off). For each line that is executed (not sure about `fn ()` defs), you'll see `+ ...` where `...` is the current line of code with all command-substitutions, environment-variable replacements, etc completed. You may see strings delimited like `'value of variable'` and the single quotes are provided by the `-x` feature to show you exactly how the vars and strings were processed, even if you had used dbl-quotes.  Think of it as normalizing  the cmd. (edited)